# React native Custom button not clickable only on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have the following component which the onPress method works perfectly on Android but not in iOS:

```
export default class Tag extends React.PureComponent {

static propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  accessibilityLabel: PropTypes.string,
  width: PropTypes.string,
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  borderColor: PropTypes.string,
  backgroundColor: PropTypes.string,
  color: PropTypes.string
};

static defaultProps = {
  marginTop: 0,
  secureTextEntry: false,
  autoCapitalize: 'none',
  backgroundColor: "white",
  color: "black",
  marginLeft: 0
}

render() {
  const { onPress } = this.props;

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={onPress}style={[styles.tag, { backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor, marginLeft: this.props.marginLeft}]}>
      <Text style={{color: this.props.color, fontWeight:"bold", fontSize:15}}>{this.props.value}</Text>
  </TouchableHighlight>
);
}
}

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tag: {
    padding: 5,
    color: 'white',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
  });
```

I use it like that:

```
<Tag onPress={() => console.log("TEST TEST")} marginLeft={0} value={"EDIT"}/>
```

But nothing is printed in the console. What is missing ?

Comment: I think that TouchableHighlight is not supported by IOS, you can use instead TouchableOpacity, you will have to conditioning it using  Platform module, Ie. if(Platform.OS === “android”) { <TouchableHighlight> ... } else { <TouchableOpacity> ...} hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work with TouchableOpacity as well..